# В скетче ардуино, не могу найти как прописать код для единоразового выполнения команды

Tags: c++

Пишу код для ардуинки. Принимаю сигнал от аналогового лазерного датчика расстояния, далее перевожу в цифровой сигнал который потом переводится в "10"( ну десять пунктов), после подаётся сигнал на шаговый двигатель. Но тут проблема. Как сделать что-бы когда например датчик останавливается на расстоянии "5" и расстояние не меняется!. Двигатель не повторял цикл раз за разом. А сделал условие и остановился находясь в той же точке расстояния "5"

Comment: Сохранять расстояние в переменную, и на следующей итерации сравнивать текущее расстояние с предыдущим.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую. Только бы найти как сохранить данные в переменную)

Comment: Ну это самый базовый C/C++, я думаю тут вы справитесь

Comment: НЕ могу понять. Даже если я сохраняю в переменные все значения с датчика. И потом сравниваю. Все равно по кругу оно доходит до условия где делает шаг и так всё равно  все время крутит мотор. нужно при следующем цикле как бы перепрыгнуть первое условие с шагом и смотреть следующие условия. как это сделать не пойму. Наверно с помощью функции.

Comment: Просто после 10 шагов, я сравниваю предыдущее показание если оно одинаково, оно не делает 0 шагов. Но потом когда итерация начинает с начала кода оно опять делает 10 шагов.

Comment: Другими словами: асли "а =2" делаем 10 шагов, потом "B =2" если a=b делаем 0 шагов или выходим из цикла, но потом  читает код сначала сверху вниз и опять "a=2" делаем 10 шагов. А надо что-бы пропустило первую часть кода. И начинало со следующего условия.